# How do I draw a world rectangle as a GUI

Tags: unity

I would like to draw a perspective green rectangle that glows (=it constantly changes its alpha between 0 an 1).

I already achieved this, but not as a GUI element, but as a real 3D object.

In order to show this rectangle in front of everything else, I have to turn this into a GUI element. And I don't know how I would draw a perspective rectangle that constantly changes its alpha on the GUI.

[image]

I do not only mean the math behind it, but also how to do it exacetly:
Do I use actual materials, or do I use an image in the size of the green box?

Thank you.

Edit:

This is what I'm trying to rebuild:
[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Unity - Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)?

Comment: @TomTsagk Yes, I have. However, I'm not sure how to deal with this case ideally.

Comment: Well, in screen space, it wouldn't be a rectangle.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what you're trying to achieve some more? I didn't really understand what's your goal and why you're trying to do it this way.

Comment: @iQew I would like to draw a perspective green rectangle that glows (=it constantly changes its alpha between 0 an 1). I already achieved this, but not as a GUI element, but as a real 3D object. In order to show it in front of everything else, I have to turn this into a GUI element. And I don't know how I would draw a perspective rectangle that constantly changes its alpha on the GUI. Thank you!

Comment: I am struggling to decipher what issue you're having. When asked to elaborate on the problem you restated the original issue description almost verbatim, I think it would help users engage with your post to understand more context. What have you attempted and why has it not worked? Why does a "real 3D object" not work in your context? Why does it have to be a UI object? Have you tried creating a worldspace canvas? Would a UI object in a worldspace canvas with an alpha lerpin script work? Maybe check out [the unity docs on worldspace UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html)?

Comment: Also, Unity has multiple UI/GUI "toolkits" which can be a major source of confusion. When searching online for Unity UI advice or tutorials you need to determine which UI toolkit is being used and if it is appropriate/applicable for your specific situation. To understand these use cases and different toolkits, check out [the Unity manual UI toolkit page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIToolkits.html), especially the table located at the bottom of the page. Worth noting, since you mentioned "GUI" repeatedly, the Unity IMGUI package is recommended only for custom Editor UI and debug displays.

Comment: "In order to show this rectangle in front of everything else, I have to turn this into a GUI element" do you really? Why not just modify the depth layering instead? Is your question really "How can I draw this rectangle in front of other content?" — ie. if we solve that without touching GUI, does that still achieve what you need?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, I really have to do this using the GUI. I'm 100% sure. Doing it via the depth layer did not work. I don't remember why exactely, but I know that it did not work due to some other configuration that I needed to have. If it's important to you, I can go through it again until I see why exactely it didn't work, but rest assured that it was not possible.

Comment: I believe the reason why it didn't work was that I'm using HDRP. In another thread we discussed the following: "Looks like the HDRP was changed between 2018 and 2019 to disable clear backgrounds." I believe that was the reason why depth layer didn't work here as well.

Comment: You seem to be very focused on doing it the way you have in mind. There's always multiple ways to solve issues and people will be able to give you better help, if you mention what exactly you're trying to achieve. Not as in technical details like you already mentioned, but what kind of effect you're trying to achieve. Can you give an example of another  game that does what you're trying to do? Then people can tell you more about how the other game might have done it and thus how you can solve it in your project.

Comment: @iQew Thank you. This question is the result of at least 2 other questions where I established what can be done and what can not be done due to the nature of my project (HDRP), for example here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173059/render-order-for-3d-meshes

Comment: You know the specific options you tried didn't work You have no evidence that you tried every possibility. There are often many ways to get a similar effect. It sounds like you're describing camera layering, while what I had in mind was modifying the shader used to draw the rectangle. Jumping to such conclusions can limit you.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think we discussed an identical situation here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96731/discussion-between-tmighty-and-dmgregory It was turned out not to be doable this way with HDRP (due to missing Clear Flags), so I refrained from doing it that way.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong — as I said above, you're talking about camera layering, and that's not what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend always asking about your goal, rather than the method you think might help you achieve your goal. ie. "How can I draw a rectangle over 3D content that's in front of it in HDRP?" rather than "How do I draw a world rectangle as GUI?"

This avoids [the X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), helping you get the outcome you want without distractions or unnecessary constraints. You'll often get solutions much easier than the way you thought of so far.

Here, I think using the GUI is a red herring. We can do this much more easily using shaders.

Create a new unlit shader (the old way - we don't need a shader graph to work with HDRP if we're not using lighting for this effect), and modify it like so:

```
// I called mine "Always in Front"
Shader "Unlit/AlwaysInFront"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        // Add a color tint parameter so you can get your desired green.
        _Color ("Color", color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // Add the transparent queue to render after the opaque objects.
        // You can use "Queue"="Transparent+100" if you need to get in front
        // of other stuff in the transparent queue, like a worldspace Canvas.
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        // Turn off the depth test, so we don't hide occluded fragments.
        // And also disable Z writes so we don't muck up the depth buffer.
        ZTest Off
        ZWrite Off
        // Enable alpha blending for transparency. You could use premultiplied 
        // alpha here if you want to tint and glow with one pass.
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            // I stripped out the fog sections since I don't expect to need them.
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            // Add color parameter.
            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Tint the texture using our color.
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result in the HDRP test scene. The green quad is actually behind the workbench, and parallaxes as you'd expect for an object at that position, but renders over the opaque 3D objects in front of it. I also added a worldspace canvas with a gun sprite on it, in front of the workbench, to show we can render over worldspace GUI too, even when our quad is behind it.

[image: Translucent green quad drawing over everything in HDRP construction scene]

Screenspace GUI can still layer on top of this for drawing your "E" / "6" markers on top. The "always on top" behaviour applies only to depth-tested objects in the 3D scene drawn before this material in the queues.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please give me so time to test it.